# Does Django emit signals when email messages are sent?

Tags: django, email, logging, signals

Would like to know if signals are emitted when an email is sent using send_mail or send_mass_mail and how to listen in on them. 
Or do I have to emit signals myself.

My use case is I want to log whenever an email is sent. The issue is that I do not want to have to mechanically log the sending of emails as this could be scattered over many parts of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no built-in signals for emails, however, you can roll your own solution.

I suggest you override your email backend class and add logging logic there. Every email backend class in Django should have `send_messages` method which's responsible for sending messages. You could add your logging logic there or emit a signal from the method.

For example: let's say you have `'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'` set as your `EMAIL_BACKEND` in `settings.py`,

then extend it as:

```
class LoggedEmailBackend(EmailBackend):

    def send_messages(self, email_messages):
        if not email_messages:
            return
        with self._lock:
            new_conn_created = self.open()
            if not self.connection or new_conn_created is None:
                # We failed silently on open().
                # Trying to send would be pointless.
                return
            num_sent = 0
            for message in email_messages:
                sent = self._send(message)
                if sent:
                    num_sent += 1
                    # DO THE EMAIL LOGGING OR EMIT A SIGNAL HERE.
            if new_conn_created:
                self.close()
        return num_sent
```

Then in settings.py set `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'custom.backends.LoggedEmailBackend'`.

Now all the emails that go through this email backend will get logged or issue a signal (depending on which approach you decide to pick).